# How to add <tr> with delete button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented JavaScript functions for add `<tr>` with a delete button and edit button by clicking a button. Newly added delete button is not working properly. Edit button is working fine.

When i add a new `<tr>` manually working correctly. please help me to solve this. I have mentioned my code below.

newFile.html

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="maintable">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Game Code#</th>                                                 
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <th></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>CHT01</td>
          <td>2. Haricane Women</td>
          <td>LKR. 500.00</td>
          <td style="float: right">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" ></i> Delete</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
$("#addnewrecord").click(function () { 

        $("#maintable").each(function () {

            var tds = '<tr>';
            //*jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {*
                tds += '<td>' + $('#inputGroupSelect01code option:selected').text(); + '</td>';
                tds += '<td>' + $('#inputGroupSelect01dscr option:selected').text(); + '</td>';
                tds += '<td> LKR.' + $('#bidprice').val(); + '</td>';
                tds += '<td style="float: right"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" ></i> Delete</button>  </td>';
            /*});*/
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

newfile.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function SomeDeleteRowFunction(table,child) { 
                table.find(child).remove();
    // you can also play with table and child (child is tr)
      }
          $(".delete").click(function(){

              swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
              })
              .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
          var $tbl = $(this).closest('table');
                  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
                  SomeDeleteRowFunction($tbl,$tr);
                  swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                  });
                } else {
                  swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                }
              });

          });

      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the onclick action after you created your element. You can add to your js

```
function loadClick () {
     $(".delete").click(function(){

          swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
          })
          .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
      var $tbl = $(this).closest('table');
              var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
              SomeDeleteRowFunction($tbl,$tr);
              swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                icon: "success",
              });
            } else {
              swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
          });

      });
}
```

and in your html :

```
if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
     $('tbody', this).append(
} 
else {
     $(this).append(
}
loadClick();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick resplonse...but this is not working..When i click delete button nothing happen... :(

Comment: Ok, we'll find what is not working. What is happening if you add `$(".delete").click(function () { console.log('works !') })` after the else then click on the button ?

Comment: add it after the  : `$("#maintable").each(function () { ... }`

Comment: when i do add `console.log('works !')` not print taht in console :(

Answer (score 0):

note quite how I would have tackled it, but this is a bit tidier and still aimed at your html - I'm unclear on what swal is, a promise - when it return what is the value of this ?

swal can be subbed back in where I have confirm - but I recommend using window.confirm to get it working.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    let dFunc = function() {

        console.log( this); // this is a tr to be sure

        let tr = $(this);
        if ( window.confirm( 'are you sure ?')) {   // or whatever swal is
            tr.remove();

        }

    }

    $(".delete").on('click', function(e){   // jquery style
        dFunc.call( $(this).closest('tr')); // "call" dFunc on the tr

    });

    // above has taken care of what is on the page

    $("#addnewrecord").click(function () { 

            $("#maintable").each( function () { // each -  ? ok ? multiple ?


            var btn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" ></i> Delete</button>');
            btn.on('click', function(e){    // jquery style
                dFunc.call( $(this).closest('tr')); // "call" dFunc on the tr

            });

            var tds = $('<tr />');
            //*jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {*
            tds.append( '<td />').html( $('#inputGroupSelect01code option:selected').text());
            tds.append( '<td />').html( $('#inputGroupSelect01dscr option:selected').text());
            tds.append( '<td />').html( 'LKR.' + $('#bidprice').val());

            var cell = $('<td style="float: right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button></td>');
            cell.append( btn);  // btn already has click active and defined
            /*});*/

            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }

        });

    });

});
```